# Setting a new registry key and all properties in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to test for 32 vs 64 bit and then create either one or two new keys depending upon the environment.

I would like to keep the code simple if I can and just set the Type, Name, Value, etc all at once if I can. Looking online it seems like it can be done, but whenever I try to run it, I just get prompted for a Type:

Looking for assistance / insight.

It seems pretty straightforward, here is what I am starting with:

```
$RegLocation1 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_USER32_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_HARDENING\"
$RegLocation2 = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_USER32_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_HARDENING"

If ([System.Environment]::Is32BitProcess) {
    New-Item -Path $RegLocation1 -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegLocation1 -Name "iexplore.exe" -Value 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PropertyType DWord 
}Else {
    New-Item -Path $RegLocation1 -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegLocation1 -Name "iexplore.exe" -Value 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PropertyType DWord 
    New-Item -Path $RegLocation2 -Force
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegLocation2 -Name "iexplore.exe" -Value 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PropertyType DWord
}
```

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` -> `registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKLM:`

Comment: `[System.Environment]::Is32BitProcess` -> `![System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test for whether the current process is 32- or 64-bit, you need to test `[System.Environment]::Is64Process`.

If, on the other hand, you want to add the `Wow6432Node` key base on whether the *operating system* is 32- or 64-bit, you need to test `[System.Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem`.

To avoid too much code duplication, store the key paths in an array and add the `Wow6432Node` one based on the test, and then iterate over them in a loop:

```
$RegLocations = @("HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_USER32_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_HARDENING")

if([System.Environment]::Is64BitProcess){
    $RegLocations += "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ALLOW_USER32_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_HARDENING"
}

foreach($Key in $RegLocations)
{
    if(-not(Test-Path $Key)){
        New-Item -Path $Key -Force
    }
    New-ItemProperty -Path $Key -Name "iexplore.exe" -Value 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -PropertyType DWord 
}
```

Comment: Will your script create those new registry Keys if they don't exist?

I see the testing for 64 bit, and removing the 32 bit test all together, that makes sense, but there isn't anything to create a new Key.

What am I missing?

OK, I think I see where I miscommunicated. 
-  FEATURE_ALLOW_USER32_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_HARDENING is the new Key I need to make. Then I need to make a dword inside the key (1 for 32 bit) (2 for 64 bit) and set the dword value to 1.

Does that help?

Thank you for your help as well!

Comment: @HowToComputer If the key exists already it will be overwritten (including all subkeys and existing values), thanks to the `-Force` switch. If it does not already exist it will simply be created - so yes, it does exactly what you describe

Comment: @HowToComputer Added a condition to test if the key already exists

Comment: Thank you again. I am stuck on what is being assigned to the $Key array, but yours worked right away.

SOLVED

Comment: @HowToComputer The `foreach` loops runs as many times as there are items in the `$RegLocations` array, each time assigning the next value in the array to the `$Key` variable (which in this case is then a string, not an array)

Comment: If my answer solves your question, please consider "accepting" it by clicking the checkmark on the left